# Is there any jar file is defined in 3D environment can be used in writting Netlogo extension, for example the path has pzcor?

Tags: java, jar, netlogo

I am rewriting a NetLogo extension by Java, the original extension is 
[NetlogoAStarPathFinding2D](https://github.com/holtri/NetlogoAStarExt)

For the path method in the Netlogo.jar library included in the class path, the value members of path only have pxcor and pycor, see
[definition of path in Netlogo.jar](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/api/Patch.html)

I want to rewrite the extension, the target agent is in a 3D environment, and planning the path from current agent to target agent. Since the agent location is [xcor, ycor, zcor], the location of path is [pxcor, pycor, pzcor]. Therefore, the Netlogo.jar can not meet my purpose.

Is there any jar file is defined in 3D environment can be used in writting Netlogo extension, for example the path has pzcor?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a different jar. NetLogo.jar has all of NetLogo 3D in it.

You just need to use `Patch3D` instead of `Patch`.

Comment: :) Now, I made the big checkmark green. Is it right? :)